# When is Noether charge quantized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory, noethers-theorem, discrete

Noether charge is the generator of the corresponding global symmetry. My question is when a Noether charge is quantized? How does the charge quantization is related to the compactness of the symmetry group?

Answer (score 5):

I am interpreting "quantized" as "discrete",i.e., in proper mathematical terms "pure point spectrum" if referring to the spectrum of the self-adjoint generator representing the charge associated with a continuous dynamical symmetry.

If a Lie group $G$ is **compact**, then all irreducible representations $G \ni g \mapsto U_g$ are finite dimensional and every unitary (strongly-continuous) representation is a *direct orthogonal sum* of a countable class finite dimensional representations (assuming as is the standard, that the Hilbert space of the theory is separable).
$$U_g = \oplus_k U^{(k)}_g\:.$$ 
Since, in finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, the spectra of operators is always *pure-point spectra* (discrete) and  a generator  $Q$ (the conserved charges) of a generic unitary rep is the sum of the corresponding generators  of its finite dim representations,
$$Q= \oplus_k Q^{(k)}\:,$$
 the spectrum of generators are the closure of the union of the spectra of subgenerators. 
$$\sigma(Q)= \overline{\cup_k \sigma(Q^{(k)})}$$
 The final spectrum $\sigma(Q)$ is therefore a pure point-spectrum barring possibly accumulation points of $\cup_k \sigma(Q^{(k)})$ which stay in the continuous part of the spectrum if are not elements of $\cup_k \sigma(Q^{(k)})$ itself. However $\sigma_c(Q)$, if any, has not much relevance here. As a matter of fact, $\sigma_c(Q)$ cannot include any interval $(a,b)$ since the proper eigenvectors of $Q$ form a Hilbert basis and the spectral projector associated to $(a,b)$ should projects onto a closed subspace orthogonal to all eigenvectors.

A typical example is the case of $SU(2)$ representations where the generators (the components of angular momentum) have pure point spectrum since there are no accumulation points of the union of the sets $\sigma_J := \{j = 0,\pm 1/2, \pm 1, \pm 3/2, \ldots \:|\: -J \leq j \leq J\}$ and $J=0,1/2, 1, 3/2, \ldots$.

Compactness is only a sufficient condition for these features of the spectrum of  generators. Even if $G$ is non-compact *some* generators may have discrete spectrum: think of $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ in particular.

Regarding the electric charge, *if we assume that this is nothing but the generator of a strongly-continuous unitary representation* of $U(1) \ni \theta \mapsto e^{i\theta Q}$, it must be $e^{i 2\pi Q} =I$ so that, passing in spectral representation, we must have $\sigma(Q) \subset \mathbb Z$ independently but in accordance with the reasoning above.

It is worth stressing that this argument does not fix the value of the elementary electric charge since a further parameter is free (depending on the units one adopts) and a rescaling $\theta \to q^{-1}\theta$, $Q \to qQ$ is always possible with the subsequent identification of $[0, 2\pi q^{-1}]$ and $U(1)$. Nevertheless, as soon as that parameter is fixed, we have $\sigma(qQ) \subset q \mathbb Z$ and the spectrum remains discrete.

Finally, the fact that symmetries are represented by (anti) unitary operators **up to phases** (Wigner-Kadison theorem) here does not matter. Indeed, it is possible to prove that projective continuous representations of $\mathbb R$ (and thus also $U(1)$) are always unitarizable. So we can always reduce to the case treated above regarding electric charge if assuming that it exists as a consequence of a $U(1)$ (continuous projective) symmetry.

Comment: It looks to me like that closure of a union of finite sets could happily be the full real line - just enumerate the rationals and split them up as a countable family of finite sets.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty You are correct, but the answer does not contradict that - "barring possibly accumulation points of $\cup_k \sigma(Q^{(k)})$" includes your case.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty Indeed it could happens as ACuriousMind stressed...

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty However, in the examined case,  no interval $(a,b)$ can be included in the continuous part of the spectrum otherwise there should exist an orthogonal subspace to the space spanned by the proper eigenvectors of the charges and this is not possible since these eigenvectors form a Hilbert basis. I added this comment to my answer. Thank you for your remark which forced me to focus further on the features of $\sigma(Q)$.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that something like that was afoot. Thanks for the clarification. CC @ACuriousMind.